# CeleryExecutor is not able to execute multi branch pipeline

Tags: airflow, celery, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver

The celery executor is not able to execute a multi-branch pipeline. The same which we tried from LocalExecutor it is able to execute multi branches.
And Celery executor is creating one message for one DAG in Redis. is this expected behavior?

taskA1->taskA2-> taskA3
|
taskB1->taskB2--|

It is picking up only one flow either taskA1 or taskB1 flow. Other flow will keep remain in the queued state.

a >> b
b >> c

a1 >> b1
b1 >> c1